# How to program an application on launch to close and automatically open the home screen (Launcher) (Wear OS)

Tags: android, wear-os

I am a beginner to programming in general and never have I programmed in Android Studio so I am probably doing all sorts wrong.

I just wanted to make a very simple app for my WearOS 3 (Based on Android 11) watch.

On launch of the application from any area (the apk) I want it to open the home screen (default Launcher). That's it. It doesn't need a UI at all.

Here is what I have so far but it gets stuck in a loop I believe. The program runs but then crashes, debug gives no information as to the reason of the crash:

```
package com.example.returntohome

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle


class MainActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val startMain = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        startMain.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
        moveTaskToBack(true)

    }
}
```

I am using Kotlin. What can I try to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent is correct. You are just missing the last bit to actually initiate the intent.

```
val startMain = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
startMain.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
startActivity(startMain) // <- Start the intent
```

Comment: Hi Dan, amazing thank you. That works perfect around approx 20% of the time. The other 80% of the time it just gets stuck on a black screen which is this app's screen on the device . In the emulator it seems to run better. At a complete guess perhaps it needs a few ms of delay to try and get more consistency? Any thoughts on this? I will have a quick play now, if I find the answer I will post back here straight away.

Comment: I cannot edit, I tried OnStart and OnResume rather than OnCreate which I think is too early in the process but still no luck. I think OnResume will resolve it but it only works once, later calls to it never runs the process :(.

Comment: Depending on what your intentions are, you can always call `finish()` after starting the intent to close your own activity if it's getting in the way.

Comment: Dan, sorry for the late reply thank you so much, this did the job perfect. App completed, thank you!
I cannot "upvote" you yet but as soon as I can I'll be sure to come back to do that! Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help Laurence. You can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.